# Webpack Package path ./dist/components/index is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

This issue has been discussed quite a lot here on SO, but none of them seem to help me.

I'm creating a chrome extension with React, TypeScript, and Webpack. I have one dependency aside from react. Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dummyname/mypackage": "^9.0.2", <-- package I want to use
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.15",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

In my `App.tsx`, I do

```
import { something } from '@dummyname/mypackage';
```

If I now run `npm run build`, everything is ok. But if I add

```
import { somethingMore } from '@dummyname/mypackage/dist/components';
```

then I get error:
`Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/components is not exported from package`
What is causing this?
My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./views/app/app.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./views/app/app.html",
            filename: "app.html"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "images" },
                { from: "css" },
            ],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'manifest.json' }
            ],
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            "@babel/preset-env",
                            "@babel/preset-react",
                            "@babel/preset-typescript",
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
};
```

The `package.json` of `@dummyname/mypackage` contains:

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./dist/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./components": {
      "require": "./dist/components/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/components/index.mjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/"
  ],
```

Comment: In `package.json` of `@dummyname/mypackage`, add `"files": ["dist"]` and check if it works.

Comment: @RobinThomas no unfortunately, same error.

Comment: @RobinThomas you meant to add this in the package.json of my project correct, the one where I installed the package?

Comment: No, it should be in `package.json` inside `@dummyname/mypackage` (and not where you use this package)

Comment: @RobinThomas I do now own the package actually, but if I check the package.json of the packge it does contain `dist/`. See question description, I updated it with the info.

Comment: not own* (instead of "now own")

Comment: Instead of `@dummyname/mypackage/dist/components` in import statement, can you use `@dummyname/mypackage/components`?

Comment: No, error displays "Cannot find module"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255174/discussion-between-robin-thomas-and-syydi).

Comment: I tried to go the react-scripts way so I removed webpack. Separated code into public and src folder with index.html and index.tsx. When running the build I get the same error.